# What is the max level a dragon can be?

Tags: dragonvale-world

What is the maximum level a dragon can be raised to in Dragonvale World?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum level for all types of dragons is 20.

[image: Level 20 Enchanted Hieroglyph Dragon]